# SOAP client function : how to pass attributes

Tags: php, soap, sabre

I am passing an object as an argument in my webservice soap client function.

The object I am using is:

```
$soap_xml_data = new stdClass;
$soap_xml_data->Version = '1.1.0';
$soap_xml_data->TargetSystem = '2';
$soap_xml_data->PrimaryLangID = 'en-us';
```

In the SOAP message Body, I expected to get:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:TheWebService TargetSystem="2" Version="1.1.0" PrimaryLangID="en-us">
```

Instead, I get

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:TheWebService TargetSystem="2" Version="1.1.0">
```

And the web service returns:

```
Client request's payload malformed: Missing PrimaryLangID attribute.
```

Why are the attributes Version and TargetSystem there in the SOAP body message first node whereas PrimaryLangID is not?